# How to create a trello card using a discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, trello

I am very new to coding java script. I am trying to make a bot to add a card into my trello and I spend countless hours on the  internet and I had no luck to find it.

```
   if(isCommand('gameban', message)){
       if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>["Admin"].includes(r.name)) )
   return message.reply("You can't use this command.");
    var username = args[1]
    if (username){
        message.channel.send(`Checking ROBLOX for ${username}`)
        roblox.getIdFromUsername(username)          
            .then(function(id){
                var bandata = (`${username}:${id}`)
                //this is where the code needs to go for trello. The card name should be is "bandata"
            }).catch(function(err){
                message.channel.send(`Sorry, but ${username} doesn't exist on ROBLOX.`)
    });
    return;
   }}
```

Board: https://trello.com/b/KcRBCOQQ/secondary-board

I want the cards to go in the list labeled "bans"

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [trello-node-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trello-node-api)

`npm install trello-node-api --save`

```js
var trelloNode = require('trello-node-api')(apiKey, oauthToken);


var data = {
        name: 'CARD_NAME',
        desc: 'Card description',
        pos: 'top',
        idList: 'LIST_ID', //REQUIRED
        due: null,
        dueComplete: false,
        idMembers: ['MEMBER_ID', 'MEMBER_ID', 'MEMBER_ID'],
        idLabels: ['LABEL_ID', 'LABEL_ID', 'LABEL_ID'],
        urlSource: 'https://example.com',
        fileSource: 'file',
        idCardSource: 'CARD_ID',
        keepFromSource: 'attachments,checklists,comments,due,labels,members,stickers'
    };
    Trello.card.create(data).then(function (response) {
        console.log('response ', response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    });
```

Comment: Hello, Everytime I test the code its going straight to the fuction error             ```}).catch(function(err){
                message.channel.send(`Sorry, but ${username} doesn't exist on ROBLOX.`)``` Could you show me an example on how I do it?

Comment: You should `console.error(err)` the error, instead of just responding as an undescriptive error to the channel. It'll tell you why it keeps having an error.

Comment: Its not showing me the error it will just go down to it cant find the user.